# Migrating Rails restful authentication users to Django

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, encryption, sha1, restful-authentication

I'm looking to migrate users of a rails app which uses the Restful Authentication module (which uses a stretched sha1 encryption algorithm) to a Django app, using the default authentication framework (which uses a plain sha1 algorithm). Does anybody know how I can make this happen? specifically, can I somehow implement the same encrytion algorithm in Django? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to create your own backend. I've done this to create an 'e-mail instead of username' and a 'ignore case' backends.

See "[Writing authentication backends](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#writing-an-authentication-backend)".